# Moving Square to Sit onto Sphere's Face?

Tags: blender

What i an trying to do is move a square onto a face of a sphere. So that the pivot of the square is at the center of the face i selected. I also need the square to be rotated so that the faces of the square are parallel/perpendicular (depending on the face) to the face of sphere.

Comment: You'd better ask the question at http://blender.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Using the exact size and position of the sphere, you can move the face exactly where it needs to be by using the G key in combination with numbers.
And if you need the sphere rotated, you can snap the 3D cursor to the centre of the sphere and rotate the plane relative to the cursor.